# Issue with "npm run server" and "npm run client" functioning at the same time. (No Error message)

Tags: node.js, npm, server, client

I've been at this for a few days and decided it might be more productive to ask smarter people.
In summary, I am using PuTTy and I can't get "npm run server" and "npm run client" to both function at the same time. No error is thrown, one will just not run while the other is running. This means I can run "npm run client" successfully but then "npm run server" will not run and vice versa.

Here is an example of my 'npm run server' running because the 'npm run client' was running:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TphRs.png)

As evidence that they both work, here is evidence that 'npm run server' indeed works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99x6d.png)

I have also used 'concurrently', and that didn't work as well:

```
"watch": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxDqN.png)

After attempting to run the second, both terminals became unresponsive and I had to close them out and reopen them.

Please, I'm not getting any errors so I don't know what's wrong. Any advice would be appreciated!

I've checked my package.json file.
I've tried using concurrently.
I've reset the instance.
checked my index.js file
checked my webpack.client.config.js file

Once again, it's hard to understand what's wrong when I don't get an error.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Thanks, I read the link. I understand that the search engine can't discern images, but there was no error message. The only reason why I added the screenshots was to support my claims that npm run server and npm run client were working independently of each other. Otherwise, the screenshots offer no value. My post wouldn't be different either way.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Search can't read text in images, but many humans can't, either. Actual text is _always_ better when sharing text. If the screenshots offer no value, omit them. If they offer _some_ value (in this case I think they do), they should be replaced with proper blocks of real text.